# Lookahead confusion

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Ok i got this example from Regular Expression Cookbook

```
^(?=.{3}$).*
```

The regex above is use to limit the length of an arbitrary pattern

If i test again 'aaabbb', it completely fail

From what i understand it look for any character that precede by any character 3 in length.SO it should match 'bbb' but its not

One more question, should lookbehind follow this pattern x(?=x)

Comment: What you are using is a look-ahead assertion as it looks at characters that are not yet consumed. A look-behind assertion would look at characters that are already consumed.

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: edited:Limit the length of an arbitrary pattern

Comment: @slier: But `^(?=.{3}$)` will only match strings of the length three. So `aaabbb` (length is six) won’t be matched.

Comment: actually im myself confused.did the lookahead assertion match position at 3rd a, so the remainder of the regex .* should match 'bbb'

Comment: A lookahead assertion is non-consuming (as Gumbo mentioned), it simply checks the upcoming characters to see if they meet with a constraint. In this case your pattern starts by looking at the start of the string, it will then perform the lookahead assertion. This will check for three characters, which will match the 3 a's respectively, it will then check for the end of the string. Since the end of the string isn't directly after the first three characters the lookahead fails, and hence the pattern fails.

Comment: @slier: No, it won’t match there because the `^` wouldn’t match. If you drop that `^` it would match that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is actually a lookahead assertion not a lookbehind assertion. The ^ anchors the match at the start of the string, it then asserts that the beginning of the string must be followed by 3 characters followed by the end of the string.

**Edit:** I should have probably mentioned that the .* at the end is then used to match those three characters since a lookahead assertion doesn't consume any characters.

Comment: what you mean by not consume any characters?

Comment: I mean that after completing the lookahead assertion, the Regex engine continues comparing the string from the point it entered the lookahead. So given the pattern `^(?=foo)(.*)$` and the input `foobar` the value capture by capture group 1 would be `foobar`. The pattern will first perform the look ahead, i.e. check if the start of the string is foo, it will then move onto the `.*` since the lookahead doesn't consume any characters, this means the first letter matched by .* is the f then the o an so forth until it has captured 'foobar'

Answer (score 4):

> From what i understand it look for any character that precede by any character 3 in length.SO it should match 'bbb' but its not

Nope! Let's take a closer look...

```
^        # The caret is an anchor which denotes "STARTS WITH"
(?=      # lookahead
   .     # wildcard match; the . matches any non-new-line character
    {3}  # quantifier; exactly 3 times
   $     # dollar sign; I'm not sure if it will act as an anchor but if it did it would mean "THE END"
)        # end of lookbehind
.        # wildcard match; the . matches any non-new-line character
 *       # quantifier; any number of times, including 0 times
```

Several problems:

1. The caret requires that the `.*` be the first characters in the string and then you're trying to lookbehind them for characters sandwhiched between the beginning `^` and the first characters `.*`.
2. Your `.{3}` actually means any three characters, not any character repeated three times ;) You actually want to know [How can I find repeated letters with a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178837/how-can-i-find-repeated-letters-with-a-perl-regex)